# load data infile statement syntax error

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following columns:
ID | Name | Source
The ID is auto-increment and primary key. I need to load data from `CSV` file. The data in the file are in the following format: Name, Source.

I need to load data from the file without duplicate. I specified the field `Name` in my table to be unique and run the following statement:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'F:/myfile.csv'
IGNORE
INTO TABLE test(name,source)
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

But I am getting error in the SQL syntax. Can you please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can specify columns in your table statement:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'F:/myfile.csv'
IGNORE INTO TABLE test 
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(`name`,`source`);
```

Try it like this. Per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html